# VueJS v-if with method always returns false

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using a `v-for` to loop through my messages. Now, what I want is to check each message date, and if the day varies, display the day, add it to my data, and continue. This means every day should only be displayed once.

```
<template v-for="(message, index) in messages">
  <div class="spacer">
    <span class="grouped-date" v-if="displayPostDate(message.created_at)">
        {{ message.created_at }}
    </span>
  </div>
</template>
```

The weird part is that in my method `displayPostDate()`, I can check for:

```
if (!this.datesDone.includes(d)) {}
```

And this works successfully when I `console.log` it, but no matter what I return, Vue never parses the right data.

Here's `displayPostDate()`:

```
let d = date.substring(0, 10);

if (!this.datesDone.includes(d)) {

    console.log('not present');
    this.datesDone.push(date.substring(0, 10));

    return true;

} else {

    console.log('present');
    return false;

}
```

Comment: the outcome of {{ displayPostDate( message.created_at) }} is always false, eventhough when I console log the return value first, it does say true in some occasions.

Answer (score 2):

#### This is what's happening...

The `displayPostDate` method has a side-effect of updating a reactive dependency (i.e., it updates `datesDone[]`), which causes another render cycle, which invokes the method again.

For example, say you have an empty `datesDone[]` and four items in `messages[]`, each with unique `created_at` dates.

1. On initial render, `displayPostDate` doesn't find any `created_at` dates in its `datesDone[]`, so it appends them to the array. It also returns `true` to display the `span`s.
2. Vue detects a change in `datesDone[]` -- a dependency of `displayPostDate`, so it starts another render cycle.
3. On the second render, `displayPostDate` finds all dates in `datesDone[]`, so no change occurs to `datesDone[]`. It also returns `false` to hide the `span`s. Since no dependency changed, Vue doesn't re-render.

#### Here's how to fix it...

First, note that invoking a method in the template is [inefficient](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods) because it gets called every time the template is rendered, which can happen multiple times, which in turn requires the method be idempotent (and not change its reactive dependencies) to avoid a render loop.

To address this issue, a simpler solution is to pre-filter the list, such that it includes only the items you want displayed (instead of conditionally rendering in the template). This has an added benefit of simplifying your template and removing the need for `datesDone[]`, assuming it has no other use than to track duplicates. I recommend creating this list as a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) so that the result is cached and not unnecessarily re-evaluated on another render cycle:

```
// script
computed: {
  uniqueMessages() {
    const uniq = this.messages.reduce((c, msg) => {
      c[msg.created_at] = c[msg.created_at] || msg
      return c
    }, {})

    return Object.values(uniq)
  }
}

// template
<div v-for="message in uniqueMessages">
  <span class="grouped-date">
    {{ message.created_at }}
  </span>
</div>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/MxRWar?editors=1010)

Answer (score -1):

Don't use methods in `v-if`s - that is buggy (as you encountered), and that is not the *Vue way* ([here's why](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/using-method-function-in-v-if/26350/2)). Use computed properties instead:

1. Add a computed property storing an array of booleans

   ```
   computed: {
     displayPostDateArr() {
       return this.messages.map(message => this.displayPostDate(message.created_at));
     }
   }
   ```
2. Conditionally display the date in your template:

   ```
   <template v-for="(message, index) in messages">
       <span
         class="grouped-date"
         v-if="displayPostDateArr[index]">
           {{ message.created_at }}
       </span>
   </template>
   ```

Comment: I have no clue what you just did but it looks cool :) I will learn learn (try) this and let you know the outcome. Thank you very much for your answer! ill come back shortly with the outcome ;)

Comment: Gives me an error "to much recursion" when I use this code btw :P

Comment: Couldn't predict that. Your code didn't include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)